# Realm InsertOrUpdate versus default with executeTransactionAsync

Tags: android, realm

I have already read that `insertOrUpdate` is faster than copyToRealm.

- I want to confirm that is still true with the latest?
- Is there any update on a bulk insert method?

The examples from the docs use `executeTransactionAsync` without any insert or copy at the end, i.e. just set fields on the object within the execute method.  I confirmed it works.

Is this the best practice? I can only guess that adding `bgRealm.insertOrUpdate` unnecessarily will be slower... right?

thanks and keep up the great work

Answer (score 0):

`insertOrUpdate()` is for inserting batch of *unmanaged* items, *without* building relations between them (as you don't receive the proxy back, therefore avoids instantiation of proxy object - super useful when inserting 3000 items or more, that you download from an external API). This **is** the "bulk insert method".

`copyToRealmOrUpdate()` is for inserting batch of unmanaged items, but you also receive the managed proxy so that you can add it to `RealmList<T>` of some other managed object.

`createObject()` creates a *managed* proxy, after which setting any of its fields will reflect in the DB without having to call `insert()`/`copyToRealm()`.